# Why custom icons add on the toolbar becomes distort?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I want to use my own made custom icons such as a brand logo and a brand text to my action bar used as toolbar but the problem is that my logo image and brand text image becomes distort when i add these on action bar even i have created separate files such as "**mdpi**" etc.I tried to create icons with image asset studio but icons becomes so smaller and resizing them effect their visual quality
[Here is the image of action bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXTWq.png) 
Now i am in the trouble suggest me better solution to add icons in a perfect way to my action bar which is used as toolbar.

Comment: Add a screenshot to visualize your problem. What do you expect them to look like, at least, drafts version with paint or something. Solution will, probably, be adding a support toolbar to get what you want

Comment: simply use adobe xd for designing or just create a artboard and put your image and adjust the size accordingly...and then export the assets directly to your android application res folder..

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=32&padding=8&color=rgba(0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200.54)&name=ic_ac_unit

Create a Generic icon of 32dp or 48dp with Asset Padding 0dp.

Check the image of my action bar.[image]

Comment: This icon is a Generic icon of 48dp.